# AutoSKLearn predict_proba equivalent?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, auto-sklearn

Is there an equivalent to SKLearn's `predict_proba` in AutoSKLearn? I can't seem to find a way to determine the confidence of AutoSKLearns predictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `predict_proba` method should be implemented for `AutoSklearnClassifier`

From [auto-sklearn documentation](https://automl.github.io/auto-sklearn/master/api.html#autosklearn.classification.AutoSklearnClassifier.predict_proba):

> `predict_proba(X, batch_size=None, n_jobs=1)`
>
> Predict probabilities of classes for all samples X.
>
> **Parameters**:
>
> - Xarray-like or sparse matrix of shape = [n_samples, n_features]
> - ...
>
> **Returns**:
>
> - yarray of shape = [n_samples, n_classes] or [n_samples, n_labels]

Which in context looks something like this:

```py
from autosklearn.classification import AutoSklearnClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)

clf = AutoSklearnClassifier(time_left_for_this_task=30)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

predictions = clf.predict_proba(X_test)
print(predictions)
```

Comment: Thanks, Alexander. Not sure how I completely missed that in the documentation.

Comment: I haven't seen many examples that use the method either, so there probably just were not very many hits when looking it up. That might change now that this question and answer exist!